# Proxy-server issue on form submit: An SSL error has occurred

Tags: node.js, ssl, axios, reverse-proxy, http-proxy

I'm attempting to create a basic form that sends data to my Airtable database. The form works fine when I add the APIkey etc to the html form but this is obviously exposed so I am attempting to make a proxy server to hide the credentials.

As this is my first time making a proxy server, I'm a little confused.

I'm using Hetzner for my server and I have created a proxy-server running on port 4000. This part all seems to be working ok from what I can gather.

I'm starting that proxy server on my Mac and using Terminal to do so by ssh'ing into the server, going to my proxy server folder and using the following command:

```
node proxy.js
```

which then runs the server and gives me the response:

```
Proxy server is listening on port 4000
```

Firstly, do I always have to enable the server on my Mac to make it work? Ideally I wanted to just leave it running and it's there when I need to use the form.

Secondly, I am getting the following error when I submit my form

```
Failed to load resource: An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made.
```

My website has an SSL certificate and when I go to the domain, I have it going to https:domain.com which shows there is a working SSL although I am dropping the www using a .htaccess file

What am I doing wrong?

Here's my code:

proxy.js

```
const express = require('express');
const axios = require('axios');
require('dotenv').config(); // Load environment variables from a .env file

const app = express();
app.use(express.json());

app.post('/submit', async (req, res) => {
  const { name, age, email, amount, postcode } = req.body;

  // Prepare Airtable API request
  const airtableData = {
    records: [
      {
        fields: {
          Name: name,
          Age: age,
          Email: email,
          Amount: amount,
          Postcode: postcode
        }
      }
    ]
  };

  try {
    const response = await axios.post(
      `https://api.airtable.com/v0/${process.env.AIRTABLE_BASE_ID}/Members`,
      airtableData,
      {
        headers: {
          'Authorization': `Bearer ${process.env.AIRTABLE_API_KEY}`,
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
      }
    );
    res.json(response.data);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error posting to Airtable:', error);
    res.status(500).json({ error: 'Internal server error' });
  }
});

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 4000;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Proxy server is listening on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Airtable Form</title>
</head>
<body>
  <form id="airtableForm">
    <label for="name">Name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name"><br><br>

    <label for="age">Age:</label>
    <input type="number" id="age" name="age"><br><br>

    <label for="email">Email:</label>
    <input type="email" id="email" name="email"><br><br>

    <label for="amount">Amount:</label>
    <input type="number" id="amount" name="amount"><br><br>

    <label for="postcode">Postcode:</label>
    <input type="text" id="postcode" name="postcode"><br><br>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>

  <script>
    document.getElementById('airtableForm').addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
      event.preventDefault(); // Prevent the default form submission
  
      // Collect form data
      const formData = {
        name: document.getElementById('name').value,
        age: parseInt(document.getElementById('age').value),
        email: document.getElementById('email').value,
        amount: parseFloat(document.getElementById('amount').value),
        postcode: document.getElementById('postcode').value
      };
  
      console.log('Before fetch request');
      fetch('https://example.com:4000/submit', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(formData)
      })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        console.log('Form data submitted successfully:', data);
        document.getElementById('airtableForm').reset();
      })
      
      console.log('After fetch request');
    });
  </script>
  
</body>
</html>
```

The only thing I can think of but I don't see it being an issue is that the index.html file is in the public_html folder and the proxy-server is in the root.